# Change to another view within a certain section

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uiview

There are three sections in my `UIView` in the iOS application. May I know how can I only change to another view within one of the sections only?

For example:

[image: main uiview with 3 section]

When I press the next page button, section 2 will change to another `UIView`. However sections 1 and sections 3 will still remain.

Any help?

Thank you so much!

Comment: How does your sections implemented right now? If they are UIViews, you can just add another one and hide it. Then, unhide it and hide section 2. You may add some animations, if you like.

Comment: Is the source of those pages static or dynamic? (e.g. a JSON or XML file taken from Server would be dynamic, and hardcoded pages are static).

Comment: Thanks for replying(: The sections 1 and 2 are scrollviews and section 3 is a uibutton. They are static(:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on Next Page button click function just do this

```
[pageSectionTwo removeFromSuperview];

[self addSubview:pageSectionTwoNewView];
```

"pageSectionTwo" this is the view which should be replaced to get another View in place
"pageSectionTwoNewView" this is the View which will show after you initial View in section 2 replaces

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Am I able to add a subview that is from another class?

Answer (score 0):

Add another UIButton, set its frame the same as UIButton in section 2, and hide it

```
UIButton *btn2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
btn2.frame = btn1.frame;
btn2.hidden = YES;
[self.view addSubView:btn2]; // This will add btn2 to you view
```

When you are ready to change your UIButtons, do the following

```
btn1.hidden = YES;
btn2.hidden = NO;
```

That will hide the first one and show the second.

Comment: actually im trying to change the uiview (section2) not the uibutton. thanks

Comment: Since UIView is an ancestor for UIButton, this will work for UIView as well.